# Unrecognized font family 'simple-line-vector'

Tags: react-native, node-modules, font-family, react-native-vector-icons, packages.json

I have installed react-native and tried to run my app, but I immediately get the error `Unrecognized font family 'simple-line-icons'`.

Then, I tried to link `react-native-vector-icons` as mentioned in other solutions in `stack-overflow` or `GitHub`. Here's the command I tried to link it :  `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`.

This prompt another error, which is : `Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null`.

Again, I looked further if someone had a solution for this second error, and the most common answer I found is that I need to upgrade my react-native. So I did with the follow command `react-native-git-upgrade` but I got this error:

`Error: react-native version in "package.json" (https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz) doesn't match the installed version in "node_modules" (0.57.1).`

Here's my project properties :

```
package.json :
...
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^2.14.0",
    "native-base": "^2.10.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
  },
...
```

```
app.json :
...
"expo": {
    ...
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    ...
...
```

I have already tried to clean my cache.

Also, I am working with npm.

Has someone encountered the same problem?

Comment: expo does not support svgs, https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons.html

Comment: How do I get rid off all svgs in my project?

Comment: can you try  remove `node_modules` file?

Comment: **And** In 'package.json', **clear** "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0","@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0" **and** run `npm install`.

Comment: Yes, I deleted `node_modules` folder and re-install it with `npm install`, removed from the package.json all the dependencies related to vector-icons, it still doesn't work

Comment: You should have deleted the two lines as described in `package.json` before you did `npm install` also you clean cache.

Comment: I just tried it, it still doesn't work, I really don't get it why...

Comment: I think it's better to build it again. you try expo upgrade `npm install -g expo-cli` **and** `expo init yourproject`

Comment: I tried that too, and it still doesn't work, it's getting pathetic how a small bug like this one is hard to resolve..